# What is AsyncCache in async library in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, caching

I am learning **async** library .
Here i found **AsyncCache** class 
Could you explain what is this and how it is works

Comment: What part of the official documentation do you find confusing? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/async/AsyncCache-class.html

Comment: You are supposed to do your own research before you ask here. What did you research so far and what questions do you have based on that research?